# How to Show two plot list that are in diferent quadrants

Tags: plotting

I'm working with version 11 of mathematica.

I have two list of complex numbers and I can plot them with ListPlot, one of these lists of points are in the up right quadrant, and the other list of numbers in the down right quadrant. Two LisPlot named PltX and PltT  that work fine. But if I do this: Show [PltX, PltT] it only shows PltX because only shows the up right quadrant
¿How can I force mathematica to show me both quadrants?

(Note: Version 11 has no ComplexPlot)

The code:

One list:

```
Table[p* 1 + I * 1 * Sqrt[-1 + p^2], {p, 1/Sqrt[2], 10, 0.1}]
```

Plot:

```
pltX = ListPlot[(Tooltip[{Re[#1], Im[#1]}] &) /@ %51, 
  AspectRatio -> 1]
```

The other list:

```
    Table[Sqrt[p] (-1 + p^2)^(1/4) * 1 - 
  I Sqrt[p] (-1 + p^2)^(1/4) * 1, {p, 1/Sqrt[2], 10, 0.1}]
```

I plot it:

```
pltT = ListPlot[(Tooltip[{Re[#1], Im[#1]}] &) /@ %55, 
  AspectRatio -> 1]
```

And then:

```
Show [pltX, pltT]
```

With `Show [{pltX, pltT}]` doesn't work too

Comment: Without any code provided - hard to say. Maybe `Show[{PltX, PltT}]` helps?

Comment: Ok, I edited it with code. It doesn't work with {} ...:-(

Comment: `Show` will use the `PlotRange` from the first plot. Try setting `PlotRange` on show, like this: `Show[..., PlotRange -> {...}]`.

Comment: PlotRange and AspectioRatio solved it.

Comment: To amplify what C.E, stated, in the documentation for `Show` under `Possible Issues` the first example states "Show uses the options from the first graphic"

Answer (score 2):

Just like C.E commented it worked with PlotRange:

```
Show [pltT, pltX,  PlotRange -> {-20, 20}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```